# Is there any difference between statement 1 and statement 2

Tags: python

statement 1 : `

```
self.__hours == 0 if self.__hours == 23 else self.__hours=+1
```

statement 2 :

```
       if self.__hours == 23 : 
        self.__hours == 0 
       else :
         self.__hours += 1
```

Is it just the styling or anything else ?

Comment: Do you mean `self.__hours = 0`?

Comment: The difference is that #1 would raise a syntax error.

Comment: The correct syntax is `variable = value1 if condition else value2` instead of `variable == value1 if condition else statement1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting syntax errors aside, the spirit of your two statements are generally equivalent. The first is a ["conditional expression"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (also called a "ternary expression").

```
self.__hours = 0 if self.__hours == 23 else self.__hours + 1
```

You are setting `self.__hours` to *something* -- either `0` or `self.__hours + 1` -- depending on the current value of `self.__hours`.

The equivalent [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement) would be:

```
if self.__hours == 23:
    self.__hours = 0
else:
    self.__hours = self.__hours + 1
```

(`self.__hours = self.__hours + 1` can also be replaced with `self.__hours += 1`.)

Answer (score 1):

In general, they're going to provide equivalent answers and be interchangeable.

One obvious difference between the two forms is that the ternary form can be used in places where an expression can be used as the body of a lambda, while the second one can't:

```
>>> x = lambda y: 0 if y > 0 else -1
>>>
>>> x(1)
0
>>> x(-1)
-1
```

or

```
>>> def fn(val):
...    print val
...
>>> y = 2
>>> fn(0 if y > 0 else -1)
0
```